# Не работает кнопка Run в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Установил Android Studio на другой компьютер и там не работает кнопка Run в Android Studiо, не могу собрать и запустить приложение. Все остальное компоненты работают, по отдельности команды выполняет.
На остальных компьютерах работает нормально.
jdk 1.8
Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Comment: Побольше информации бы. Что в ней не так? Некликабельна вообще? Кнопка Debug активна?

Comment: Кликабельная, кликается, но ничего не происходит. С кнопкой Debug то же.

Comment: Конфигурация выбрана?

Comment: Да, все настроено.

Comment: Нажмите на EditConfigurations, выберите приложение и сделайте скриншот окошка. Выложите сюда

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: У вас Windows 7?

Comment: Да, Windows 7 Максимальная, на компьютерах где работает Домашняя базовая

Answer (score 2):

Проблема найдена. Неправильно установился Android sdk, отсутствовали adb.exe и нужные ему dll-библиотеки.